# synchronizing slots in QThread -?

Tags: qt

I have 2 slot handlers in QThread- derived class:  one is timer handler and another is just asynchronous callback handler. Both have to modify the same data.

```
struct somedata {
    int max;
    int min;
    double avg;
}

...

class MyThread: QThread {

private:
    somedata m_data;

private Q_SLOTS:
    void asyncCallback(int a, int b) {
        m_data.max += a;
        m_data.min += b;
    } 

    void timer() {
        m_data.avg =(m_data.a + m_data.b)/2;
    }

}
```

Should the access to m_data be serialized in some fashion, although both method are in the same thread? 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can guarantee that your data is only ever being accessed or modified by a single thread at any time, then you don't need to work about synchronizing access to that data via thread-safety constructs.

One way to verify this is to check the return value of QThread's static `currentThread()` function when your functions are called.

Answer (score 0):

If both functions are called by same thread then you dont need to worry about the data getting changes when the other call is in the second slot.If you are not sure then the best option is to use a mutex in both the slots so that only one process or changes the value of m_data.